# Open SSRS Action URL's In a New Tab/Window

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a report PDF created using SSRS with images and I have defiend the Action - Go to Url on all the images. When clicked on the pictures I need the url to open in a new tab rather than same tab while viewing the pdf from Chrome or IE.

I tried the javascript:window.open but it doesn't work. I mean it just opens a blank new tab but not the actual URL this is when viewd from adobe however when tried to view the same from Chrome it doesn't even give me the option to click.

My URL Expression
="javascript:void window.open('https://www.gocanvas.com/values/5246297662','_blank')"

Comment: Possible duplicate... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17149244/how-to-open-url-in-ssrs-report-in-webpart-to-new-window  subtle difference between the code is you need to wrap your window.open in parenthesis after the void.

Comment: I found that to use the snippet javascript:void etc... the report needed to be deployed to the ReportServer first.

Comment: @WEI_DBA I have added the parenthesis = "javascript:void(window.open('https://www.gocanvas.com/values/5246297662', '_blank'))" but still the url opens a new blank tab instead of the URL.

Comment: @SuperSimmer44 - thanks for the response. Yes, I already tried this but it doesn't work.