# SSRS report -- open detail report with parameters in URL with relative URL so it works correctly in regions (XML and javascript involved)

Tags: javascript, http, url, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

Per the questions below, in order to open an SSRS report in a new tab or new window, one has to use javascript and a URL.

[Previous Question #1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17149244/how-to-open-url-in-ssrs-report-in-webpart-to-new-window)

[Previous Question #2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55051278/open-ssrs-action-urls-in-a-new-tab-window?noredirect=1&lq=1)

The need is to have the detail report open in several regions, such as dev-region, int-region, and production (prod).  The answers above would have *absolute* URL's, all different.  Is it possible to do this with *relative* URL's?  If so, what would the example syntax be, please?

NOTE:  It may be assumed that the two SSRS reports (the parent or summary and the child or detail) are in the *SAME* folder.  This should greatly simplify a relative URL-styntax.

Also, I was able to answer question below, the answer ALSO covers **everything** one needs to open an SSRS detail report in another window (Should work for ssrs-2008-r2 and above).

This would also help solve questions such as:

[SSRS relative URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597258/ssrs-relative-url-hyperlink)

Comment: can you identify the region from your dataset? If yes.. then why not build the URL based on the dataset value?

Comment: @Harry -- it's probably worth investigating,  I was hoping for something simpler, however

Comment: @Harry -- please see below, uses Globals!  (it is pure XML and not in the TSQL <CommandText>

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question (I had some of this information from a colleague, I had to develop some myself).  This information is scattered all over the place, but for SSRS reports, I think that this is the only one-stop concise place that I know of:

```
<Hyperlink>="javascript:void(window.open('" &amp; Globals!ReportServerUrl &amp; "/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?" &amp; Globals!ReportFolder &amp; "%2fMy+Report+Name" &amp;  chr(38) &amp;  "rs:Command=Render" &amp; chr(38) &amp;   "Input1=" &amp; Fields!GoesWithInput1.Value &amp; chr(38) &amp;  "Input2=" &amp; Fields!GoesWithInput2.Value  &amp; "'))"</Hyperlink>
```

NOTES:

1. Above is horizontally very long
2. "My Report Name" has spaces replaced
   by '+' character
3. ABOVE is XML within rdl, if using the ‘design’ (action) in designer, you   don’t use the XML
   tags and would start with “=”
4. Chr(38) is ASCII for "&" (ampersand) the & is a concat operator for the strings used within the javascript command.  Thus "ampersand escape" is involved and done two ways.
5. Note that this is a hodge-podge of Javascript and XML.  Since URL's are involved, http is also important (often https these days).
6. Finally, this is *not* TSQL-based and is not in the  using the TSQL and the dataset.  It is possible to form URL's that way, but this solution here doesn't do it that way.  I tried, and the Globals didn't seem to be available, at least in the way I tried to use them in the TSQL within the  in the XML of the rdl-file.